# Trying to get my head around (x:xs) and lists?

Tags: list, haskell, syntax, recursion

I have always been challenged by the way lists work and am confused about the whole (x:xs) concept. I just don't seem to be getting my head around it.

Example

```
select :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
select y [] = []
select y (x:xs)
    | x < y     = x : select y xs
    | otherwise = select y xs
```

P.S. I know exactly what the function does, but would anyone be able to explain the process (including especially the weird `Ord a` and `=>` signs)?

Any effective strategies would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance. Ian.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok. Let's walk through the different syntactic elements here.

**Line 1**

```
select :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
```

This is a type declaration. It is the declaration of a function (since it has `->` types).

The function has two arguments.

- The first is a single value of any type, signified by `a` (lower case means it is a polymorphic type).
- The second argument is a list of any type that is the same as the first argument.

The return value is a list of any type, the same as the argument types.

The `Ord a` component is a typeclass constraint, that says that any type this function is given must also be an instance of the `Ord` class. This is a class of types that can be compared.

**Line 2**

Now we look at line 2:

```
select y [] = []
```

This is one definition of the `select` function itself. It is very simple, containing patterns for the two arguments, and a specification of the result. It reads:

> if the first argument is any value (which we will name `y`), and the second argument is the empty list (denoted by the `[]` pattern), then `select` evaluates to the empty list.

**Line 3**

Line 3 contains the other case for lists:

```
select y (x:xs)
```

Again, this is part of the definition of the `select` function, for the case when the second argument is *not* an empty list. If it is not an empty list, then it is a list with a head, `x`, and a tail `xs`. The "cons" constructor, `(:)` combines a list head and tail. It is also how we pattern match on a list, to extract the head and tail.

By pattern matching on the head and tail of the list, with `(x:xs)`, we bind a new variable, `x`, to the value of the head of the list, and `xs` to value of the tail of the list.

**Lines 4 and 5**

The last two lines are additional *guards* that test and branch based on additional checks, should the second argument be a non-empty list:

```
| x < y     = x : select y xs
| otherwise = select y xs
```

The first guard fires when `x` is less than the first argument, `y`. If so, we return a new list with `x` at the head, and `select` applied again to the tail.

If that is not the case, then we drop `x` from the list, and return only what happens when tail is called recursively.

---

For more information on how Haskell works, I recommend introductory texts such as:

- [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good.](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)
- [Programming in Haskell.](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/book.html)
- [The Craft of Functional Programming.](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/sjt/craft2e/)

it will be worth your time.

Answer (score 2):

My Haskell is limited at best, but I'll give what answer I can in case nobody else does...

```
select :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
```

This says:

> The select function uses any type "a" such that that type is of the typeclass "Ord" (Orderable). It takes one instance of the type plus a list of the type and returns a list of 
>   the type.

If it helps, in Java this might be represented as (kindof):

```
<T implements Comparable> List<T> select(T value, List<T> listOfValues);
```

The actual function definition says:

- If an empty list is passed in, return an empty list, Otherwise
- If the first element of the list passed in is less than the value, return a list comprised of that element appended to the list resulting from evaluating the function applied to the rest of the list, Otherwise
- return a list comprised of that element appended to the list resulting from evaluating the function (ie, without the first elements)

Edit: Orderable in the above context means "you can compare values of that type against each other to determine which comes 'first'". Ie, the <, =, and > operators are defined for values of the type. "Ord" is a TypeClass defined by (in effect) the Haskell standard library (Prelude? I forget what it's called)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RHSeeger. Not quite sure what Orderable means in terms of programming though...

Comment: @maclunian: "this type is orderable" simply that you can compare two things of this type, e.g. with `<`.

Comment: Generally, a => sign denotes a constraint. It's meaning is, that the type must be an instance of the denoted typeclass (Ord implements comparison, such as <, > and <=). Actually, such a dependency is needed, whenever you want to use an operation over an unknown type.

Comment: So just confirming Eq on the other hand (i.e. f :: Eq a => ......) is for when you use the == term in the conditional part?

Comment: @maclunian : I believe that's the case, yes. Anything that is of the typeclass Ord is also of the typeclass Eq (since you need equality to define ordering), the reverse is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 1):

`(x:xs)` is for pattern-matching a cons cell.  When you say `[1,2,3]`, it's actually syntactic sugar for `1:(2:(3:[]))`.  Thus, when `select 1 [1,2,3]`, is invoked:

```
select y []     = ... -- pattern skipped; [1,2,3] does not match []
select y (x:xs) = ... -- pattern used, with y = 1, x = 1, and xs = [2,3]
```

Thus, in `(x:xs)`, `x` is the first item of the list, and `xs` is the remaining items.  This pattern will only match if the list is not empty.

As for the `Ord a =>` syntax, it means "If `a` is an instance of the type class `Ord`".  `Int` would work here because it has an instance for `Ord`, which could look like this:

```
instance Ord Int where
    (<=) = primitiveIntLessThanOrEqual
```

If you left the `Ord a` out and just said `select :: a -> [a] -> [a]`, then `x < y` would not work because it requires arguments of a type in the class `Ord`:

```
(<) :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> Bool
```

Comment: And then it will do the same with the others, won't it!

Comment: @FUZxxl I think I'm getting the picture now!